# Using Microsoft Excel as user interface for a windows form application

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I want to create a windows form application using c#, that uses Microsoft excel as interactive user interface, in the other word, I want to load the data from database to Excel, and after user modification(grouping, changing row data, ...) save back modifications to database(I want to be able load all user modifications in next time). does anybody know any good samples?

Comment: Just to be clear -  are you asking for a library, or a code sample, to control MS Excel from c#  ? That would be on-topic, whereas asking us to code it for you would not (ask on S.O). Please, read [ask] to help us to help you.

Comment: Please note that this site is about *recommending software meeting specific requirements,* not about *solving issues with software* you already have. If you intended to ask for software, please see  [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for a guide. Otherwise please check the `/help/ontopic` page of other SE sites to see where your question fits.

Answer (score 2):

This is not embedding Excel, but a Spreadsheet component that tries to provide functionality similar to Excel. Syncfusion [Spreadsheet for WPF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/sfspreadsheet) or [Spreadsheet for Windows Forms](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-forms/spreadsheet) support embedding Excel files in windows applications.

[WPF Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Spreadsheet_WPF_CS-1333550082.zip)

[Windows Forms sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Spreadsheet_WF_CS-1980087160.zip)

Note that Essential Studio is required to be installed for the samples to compile.

This control is completely independent from Microsoft Office, so it will have most of the commonly used features of Excel and also provide you with more customization capabilities. Microsoft Office is not required at all.

[image: Spreadsheet]

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: @Masoud There are some free components for reading and writing Excel files, but not for Excel like interface.